# Multipart file Sping Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm using MultipartFile to upload files in web application. Is it possible to give the ability to the user(publisher) to add some description and tags to the uploaded file, which will be used for searching later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two Media Types:

`consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE })`

And we need to pass the given parameter as Tag and Multipart file. Here, make sure we can pass only String + file not POJO + file.

`@RequestPart(“tag”) String tag, @RequestPart(“file”) List<MultipartFile> file`

Then convert the String to Json using ObjectMapper in Service layer.

`Tag tagPojo = new ObjectMapper().readValue(tag, Tag.class);`

So it would look like:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/send", consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE })
public void upload(@RequestPart(“tag”) String tag, @RequestPart(“file”) List<MultipartFile> file) {
Tag tagPojo = new ObjectMapper().readValue(tag, Tag.class);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the field in `POST` request's body:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/upload", consumes = MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
ResponseEntity<Void> uploadFile(
        @RequestParam("files") List<MultipartFile> files,    
        @RequestParam("descr") String description
);
```

and send a request for example:

[image]